# Rotate object horizontally by 90 degrees in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate a cube horizontally by 90 degrees. So I would write

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(90, 0, 0));
```

but this seems to be wrong.

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 90, 0));
```

and

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(90, 0, 0), Space.World);
```

and

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(90, 0, 0), Space.Self);
```

seem to be wrong, too. I just want to rotate it on its own axis.

How can I archieve that =?

[image]

Comment: The arrows you show are rotating around Y axis... may be you need to clarify to yourself your coordinate system...

Comment: it seems that `obj.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 90, 0));` is correct, but I need to rotate it around its local axis, otherwise it movies itself..

Comment: That's right, if you rotate respect to the world axis after having transformed your object the result will not be what you expect. Read some documentation better instead of trying to code with no knowledge about 3D.

Answer (score 2):

The cube's center point is not at its geometry's center. Which is making it move while rotating - 
[image]

You need to have the cube's center at it's geometry's center if you want to rotate it around without moving.

Answer (score 0):

vector = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0) * vector; 
Try this

Answer (score 0):

Check the pivot point of your cube
if it's imported from somewhere so it's pivot might not be in exactly 0, 0, 0 of the cube, create a new EmptyGameobject in scene, and have the cube as the child of the new obj, adjust it's position so the new gameobject is located at cube's 0,0,0 position.

And then apply rotate it should be fine. (I know the method sounds tricky, however, this is the only legit way of changing gameobject's pivot point in Unity)

---

About rotation

There's two way of rotating:

If instant rotate you should be fine

Else if you want it to rotate slowly. Use:

```
transform.Rotate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, Space.World);
```